# Tooltip on hover of elements generated by AJAX request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip using the [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) plugin on hover of a container that is dynamically generated using AJAX. I am having an extremely hard time with this and have been trying to figure this out for days now. Note: I am not getting any errors, Tooltipster is working on non-ajax elements.

I appreciate any suggestions as to how to implement this.

Many thanks in advance!

JavaScript / AJAX Call

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "get-data.php?bestItems=1",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $(".best-items-container").html(data).show();
            }
        });
```

Tooltip initialization / event

```
         $('.best-item-option').tooltipster({ 
            custom: 'hover',
            onlyOne: true,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
            position: 'left',  // display the tips to the left of the element
            theme: '.my-custom-theme'
        });
        $(document).on('hover', '.best-item-option', function(){        
            $('.best-item-option').tooltipster('show');
        });
```

Dynamic html snippet (PHP)

```
<div class="best-items-container">
    <div class="best-item-option" title="Testing Tooltip">
        <div class="hotItemName">'. $data['name'][$i].'</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your initialization code in a separate function:

```
function initTooltipster(){
..the init code here....
}
```

and then in your callback function (the 'success' part) add the line `initTooltipster()`

edit: as mentioned by Circadian, this could have some performance issues, but it's very simple, so just try and if all works well try to bind tooltipster to a specific element...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tooltipster has not been initialised for the dynamicaly added elements.

A solution could be

```
$(document).on('hover', '.best-item-option', function(){        
    $('.best-item-option').tooltipster();
    $('.best-item-option').tooltipster('show');
});
```

Though if you have many `.best-item-option` elements this will be inefficient as it will bind tooltipster again (I think). It is better to use ids and add it only to the new element.